# Visual Studio Libraries issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

ASP.net project build and run successfully, but all the code shows errors and its not allowing to access any library. Any Ideas Please?

[image: image description]

Comment: If the program compiles, I seem to remember a recent change where this breaks. Can't remember the fix. I would delete your bin folders, restart VS and maybe reboot.

Comment: I deleted bin , vs and obj files then compile then restart visual studio but no luck.

Comment: Try deleting the .vs hidden folder too.  That's where the intellisense it built.

Comment: @Neil i did but no luck. How can i change the libraries target framework to target the same .net framework of my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to installed nuget package libraries that targets different version of the .net framework of the project.

To solve the issue is check the target framework for each libraries then uninstall it and reinstall.

In my case forcing all libraries to uninstall and reinstall using the command `Update-Package -reinstall` 
Didn’t work. I had to uninstall each one by one.